# JavaScript for loop, I don't understand

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I don't understand the output of this question from CodeAcademy. It is stated in the for loop that X+=1, but why is the output printing the X index 0 for the second time? I thought it would be index 1(A) as X+=1.

```
const tags = ['G', 'A', 'T',' C'];
for (let x = 0; x < tags.length; x +=1) {
  for(let y = 1; y < tags.length - 1; y +=1) {
    console.log(`${tags[x]}${tags[y]}`,x,y);
  }
}
//output GA  GT  AA  AT  TA  TT  CA  CT
```

Output:

[image: Console Image]

Comment: You are running a nested for loop. Your "second time" `x` is actually the "first time" `x` while `y` has its second value.

Comment: What you can do to understand it better is copy the code in vscode put a breakpoint on the `console.log` line and debug it. As the code executes you will see how it progresses and what is happening when.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop starts with y = 1 and ends with y = 2 for this `tags` array. That means for each iteration of the outer loop, the `console.log` runs twice. That's why you are seeing 4 * 2 = 8 outputs printed out, where 4 is the number of iterations the outer loop goes through, and 2 is the number of iterations the inner loop goes through each time.